# Can we be specific about case sensitivity in mongoose .model() function?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to access model **Names**, but when I pass it as `.model('Names', mySchema)`. A new model with the name **names** is created and is queried the same. Is there any way I can define case sensitivity in .model func?

Answer (score 0):

As explained into [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

> Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name.

So, if your collection is `Names` or `Name` it will create `names`.

By the way you can use the third parameter while creating the model to override this behaviour and set the explicit collection name.

Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model) where it says about the third parameter:

> [collection] «String» name (optional, inferred from model name)

So if you do `.model('Names', mySchema, 'Names')` your model will be `Names`.

Not case insensitive at all but I think it fits for you.